# Data Grid filter performance wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, filter, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with textbox in the headers for filter, but the performance is not so good. This is the code for the datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="DGrdBuscar" ItemsSource="{Binding DGrdBuscarView,Mode=OneWay}" MaxWidth="1800" MaxHeight="850" MinRowHeight="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="SizeToCells" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" FrozenColumnCount="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" BorderBrush="Black" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IdTrafo" Binding="{Binding IdTrafo,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" MinWidth="130" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyleLeft}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtIdTrafo" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" MinWidth="150"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_Def}" Binding="{Binding Definitivo,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.NroDiseno_Cot}" Binding="{Binding Cotizacion,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_UserName}" Binding="{Binding UserName,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtUserName" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colPotReg1" Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_PotReg1}" Binding="{Binding PotReg1,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtPotReg1" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_UnomAT}" Binding="{Binding UnomAT,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtUnomAT" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_UnomBT}" Binding="{Binding UnomBT,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtUnomBT" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_Frec}" Binding="{Binding Frecuencia,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtFrec" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Observaciones}" Binding="{Binding ObservacionesSearch,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TxtObs" TextChanged="Txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_GrupoCon}" Binding="{Binding GrupoCon,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Data.GrupoCon_IsCollapsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_NroDiseno}" Binding="{Binding NroDiseno,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Resources.Buscar_NroSerie}" Binding="{Binding NroSerie,Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColHeaderStyle}"/>                                                          
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The datagrid is fill from a database and it can contains thousands of rows.
And in the code behind:

```
Private Sub Txt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim t As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim filter As String = t.Text
        If filter = "" Then
            'v_MainWindowVM.BuscarVM.DGrdBuscarView.Filter = Nothing
            Select Case t.Name
                Case "TxtPotReg1"
                    filterPotReg1 = ""
                Case "TxtUnomAT"
                    filterUnomAT = ""
                Case "TxtUnomBT"
                    filterUnomBT = ""
                Case "TxtFrec"
                    filterFrec = ""
                Case "TxtUserName"
                    filterUserName = ""
                Case "TxtObs"
                    filterObs = ""
                Case "TxtIdTrafo"
                    filterIdTrafo = ""
            End Select
            v_MainWindowVM.BuscarVM.DGrdBuscarView.Filter = New System.Predicate(Of [Object])(Function(o) TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).PotReg1.ToString.StartsWith(filterPotReg1) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UnomAT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomAT) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UnomBT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomBT) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).Frecuencia.ToString.StartsWith(filterFrec) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UserName.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterUserName.ToUpper) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).ObservacionesSearch.Contains(filterObs) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).IdTrafo.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterIdTrafo.ToUpper))
        Else
            Select Case t.Name
                Case "TxtPotReg1"
                    filterPotReg1 = t.Text
                Case "TxtUnomAT"
                    filterUnomAT = t.Text
                Case "TxtUnomBT"
                    filterUnomBT = t.Text
                Case "TxtFrec"
                    filterFrec = t.Text
                Case "TxtUserName"
                    filterUserName = t.Text
                Case "TxtObs"
                    filterObs = t.Text
                Case "TxtIdTrafo"
                    filterIdTrafo = t.Text
            End Select
            v_MainWindowVM.BuscarVM.DGrdBuscarView.Filter = New System.Predicate(Of [Object])(Function(o) TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).PotReg1.ToString.StartsWith(filterPotReg1) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UnomAT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomAT) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UnomBT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomBT) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).Frecuencia.ToString.StartsWith(filterFrec) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).UserName.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterUserName.ToUpper) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).ObservacionesSearch.Contains(filterObs) AndAlso TryCast(o, ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar).IdTrafo.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterIdTrafo.ToUpper))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMsg("Subrutina ITD.Buscar.Txt_TextChanged", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What can I do to improve the performance?
When I start writing in the filter after the second letter it take too long.

Comment: Not really sure how much you can do here, And I can even guarantee the filter predicate doesn't get simplified at run time but would it make any difference if you could remove all the TryCast calls and work on actual data types?  Maybe a slight change of approach might be an idea to.  Rather than having filtering on TextChanged maybe create an "Apply Filter" button to apply all filters at once.  Apart from that the only thing maybe around fine tuning the control of re-drawing your filtered grid

Answer (score 0):

I improve the performance by doing the TextChanged method Async, like this:

Private mostRecentfilter As String = ""

```
Private Async Sub Txt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim t As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim filter As String = t.Text       'get the entered text

        mostRecentfilter = filter        'set the instance variable for entered text
        Await Task.Delay(550)          'wait 0.55 second in case they keep typing
        'if they didn't keep typing
        If filter = mostRecentfilter Then
            'do what you were going to do
            If filter = "" Then
                Select Case t.Name
                    Case "TxtPotReg1"
                        filterPotReg1 = ""
                    Case "TxtUnomAT"
                        filterUnomAT = ""
                    Case "TxtUnomBT"
                        filterUnomBT = ""
                    Case "TxtFrec"
                        filterFrec = ""
                    Case "TxtUserName"
                        filterUserName = ""
                    Case "TxtObs"
                        filterObs = ""
                    Case "TxtIdTrafo"
                        filterIdTrafo = ""
                End Select
            Else
                Select Case t.Name
                    Case "TxtPotReg1"
                        filterPotReg1 = t.Text
                    Case "TxtUnomAT"
                        filterUnomAT = t.Text
                    Case "TxtUnomBT"
                        filterUnomBT = t.Text
                    Case "TxtFrec"
                        filterFrec = t.Text
                    Case "TxtUserName"
                        filterUserName = t.Text
                    Case "TxtObs"
                        filterObs = t.Text
                    Case "TxtIdTrafo"
                        filterIdTrafo = t.Text
                End Select
            End If
            v_MainWindowVM.BuscarVM.DGrdBuscarView.Filter = New Predicate(Of Object)(Function(o As ClassDataBase.DataGridBuscar) o.IdTrafo.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterIdTrafo.ToUpper) AndAlso o.PotReg1.ToString.StartsWith(filterPotReg1) AndAlso o.UnomAT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomAT) AndAlso o.UnomBT.ToString.StartsWith(filterUnomBT) AndAlso o.Frecuencia.ToString.StartsWith(filterFrec) AndAlso o.UserName.ToUpper.StartsWith(filterUserName.ToUpper) AndAlso o.ObservacionesSearch.Contains(filterObs))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMsg("Subrutina ITD.Buscar.Txt_TextChanged", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And also removing the trycast.